# Issue with address locator in ArcGIS 10.1

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1, arcgis-desktop, geocoding

I am attempting to geocode a table of addresses for a client. I researched into how to create your own address locator and have two separate reference sources: one that has exact address information for our county and another that has road information.

I have made a locator for addresses using the US Address - Single House style, and one for roads (I experimented with one range/dual ranges style). When I make a composite locator using both of these and add it to ArcMap during geocoding, I am not presented with an "Address" field input. I only have street or intersection, city, state, zip.

What setting exactly will allow me to input the physical house number?

Edit:
I should mention that the client data has addresses split into multiple fields such as: House_NO, ST_NAME, CITY.

Should I simply combine the house_no and st_name fields?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like combining the fields was what I was looking for. I was so set on using separate fields it didn't occur to me to try that.

If anyone isn't super comfortable with the field calculator, I used this to combine the separate fields together:
[Street_Num] & " " & [Street_Name]

Answer (score 0):

It could be more accurate or it could be less accurate because it's based on the USCB TIGER data set, but have you considered using an address validation service to quickly handle the geocoding of your list of addresses?  As long as they have an address and a zip code or even an address and a city/state, most address validation services should be able to easily handle that.  100,000 addresses should be done in about 7 minutes.

A quick google search for "address validation" will find a number of them for you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have learned recently:

10.0+ Locators using the US Address Styles (dual & single side as well as Single House) require both the City State fields be populated by data (ie your input table must have these columns) to generate a result.  <10.0 this was not the case, which is why you see a lot of this going on.  The locator will work and create fine, but it won't return any results for whatever reason.

Rebuild the locators is tricky and error prone in 10.0+.  If you have address locators "bundled" into the composite you can do like we did and just overwrite the locator participating in the composite to keep your composite locator current.  Do NOT try to delete the existing locators in the bundle and recreate them as the composite has a "lock" on them.  Overwriting them works fine however.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly; none of ESRI's Geocoders will allow you enter the house number and street as seperate values in your search. When you define your Geocoder and select what you address/range and street name values these are used by the software to build a cross-talk index.

This index is used by ESRI when the address line is parsed internally in the software to break the address up into component parts. You are not afforded the ability to choose which address components your inputs are queried against.

Most organizations that require this level of flexibility will do a direct DB Query with the benefit of optimized indexing to reduce the dependency on the ESRI layer.